# Could not start the game server

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I tried to run the game as explained here...

https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server

But got this error:

```
# java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar  nogui
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.minecraft.server.Main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/server/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

I installed JDK using:

```
apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
```

I am using ARM Ubuntu EC2 instance.

---

Update:

Managed to install Java. But getting a different error this time :)

```
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.17.1
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on 18.210.57.140:25564
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[04:40:16] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[04:40:16] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
[04:40:16] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[04:40:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[04:40:16] [Server thread/ERROR]: Exception stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "abr.o_()" because "â˜ƒ" is null
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:588) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.u(SourceFile:624) ~[server.jar:?]
        at aas.u(SourceFile:585) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(SourceFile:734) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:270) ~[server.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

Comment: You need to update your Java install

Comment: Some more info on Java versions and class file versions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Comment: How do I update Java on ARM? Most of the instructions found through google do not apply to ARM processor.

Comment: If you use ARM 64-bit then [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/install/) has 16 here: https://jdk.java.net/16/. If you need ARM 32-bit, a user found a way to install it here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/127394/33110